# jquery aggregates onclick on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div where I on pageload binds a click function like below

```
 <div class="document-short-list-item" data-d-id="5" data-w-id="16" data-s-id="15">Klik her for at tilføje</div>

$(".document-short-list-item").click(function () {
    addToShortList(this);
});
```

The addToShortList performs the following:

```
  $(element).removeClass('document-short-list-item').addClass('document-short-list-item-added').on('click', removefromShortList(element));
```

and the removefromShortList reverses the same

```
 $(element).removeClass('document-short-list-item-added').addClass('document-short-list-item').on('click', addToShortList(element));
```

The problem is that the above code aggregates on each click, this means the both addToShortList and removeFromShortList runs multiple times on click

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 0):

Because every click event calls another `.on()` to add more handlers.

It's almost always a bad idea to bind/unbind handlers in their own binding events and often leads to this kind of situation.  Instead, you can rely on [the functionality of `.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to dynamically execute as the classes change.  This is called "event delegation".

Basically bind the click event to a common parent element (`document` often works, unless anything is stopping the event propagation).  Something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".document-short-list-item", function () {
    $(this)
        .removeClass("document-short-list-item")
        .addClass("document-short-list-item-added");
});
$(document).on("click", ".document-short-list-item-added", function () {
    $(this)
        .removeClass("document-short-list-item-added")
        .addClass("document-short-list-item");
});
```

This will attach the click handler to the document itself, but when handling that click it will filter the originating element by the selector argument.  So any originating `.document-short-list-item` will invoke the first handler, and any originating `.document-short-list-item-added` will invoke the second handler.  This way you only need to set these handlers once on page load and they internally filter as needed.

---

Alternatively, if this approach might work in your situation, you can use a single handler which will simply toggle the classes.  For example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".document-short-list-item, .document-short-list-item-added", function () {
    $(this)
        .toggleClass("document-short-list-item")
        .toggleClass("document-short-list-item-added");
});
```

Which would respond to either originating element (since both are in the selector) and toggle both classes, regardless of which one is currently active.